# ksort() is producing as incorrect result

Tags: php, sorting, ksort

The original array is this:

```
Array
(
    [Danmark] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 39
            [name:protected] => Danmark
            [code:protected] => DK
            [stringIndex:protected] => DENMARK
        )

    [Tyskland] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 59
            [name:protected] => Tyskland
            [code:protected] => DE
            [stringIndex:protected] => GERMANY
        )

    [Irland] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 78
            [name:protected] => Irland
            [code:protected] => IE
            [stringIndex:protected] => IRELAND
        )

    [Italien] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 81
            [name:protected] => Italien
            [code:protected] => IT
            [stringIndex:protected] => ITALY
        )

    [Holland] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 119
            [name:protected] => Holland
            [code:protected] => NL
            [stringIndex:protected] => NETHERLANDS
        )

    [Nya Zeeland] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 122
            [name:protected] => Nya Zeeland
            [code:protected] => NZ
            [stringIndex:protected] => NEW_ZEALAND
        )

    [Polen] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 138
            [name:protected] => Polen
            [code:protected] => PL
            [stringIndex:protected] => POLAND
        )

    [Spanien] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 161
            [name:protected] => Spanien
            [code:protected] => ES
            [stringIndex:protected] => SPAIN
        )

    [Sverige] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 166
            [name:protected] => Sverige
            [code:protected] => SE
            [stringIndex:protected] => SWEDEN
        )

    [Schweiz] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 167
            [name:protected] => Schweiz
            [code:protected] => CH
            [stringIndex:protected] => SWITZERLAND
        )

    [England] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 185
            [name:protected] => England
            [code:protected] => GB
            [stringIndex:protected] => UNITED_KINGDOM
        )

    [Osterrike] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 197
            [name:protected] => Osterrike
            [code:protected] => AT
            [stringIndex:protected] => AUSTRIA
        )

    [Belgien] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 236
            [name:protected] => Belgien
            [code:protected] => BE
            [stringIndex:protected] => BELGIUM
        )

)
```

And after I call:

```
ksort($countries, SORT_STRING);
```

I get this:

```
Array
(
    [Osterrike] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 197
            [name:protected] => Osterrike
            [code:protected] => AT
            [stringIndex:protected] => AUSTRIA
        )

    [Belgien] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 236
            [name:protected] => Belgien
            [code:protected] => BE
            [stringIndex:protected] => BELGIUM
        )

    [Danmark] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 39
            [name:protected] => Danmark
            [code:protected] => DK
            [stringIndex:protected] => DENMARK
        )

    [Tyskland] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 59
            [name:protected] => Tyskland
            [code:protected] => DE
            [stringIndex:protected] => GERMANY
        )

    [Irland] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 78
            [name:protected] => Irland
            [code:protected] => IE
            [stringIndex:protected] => IRELAND
        )

    [Italien] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 81
            [name:protected] => Italien
            [code:protected] => IT
            [stringIndex:protected] => ITALY
        )

    [Holland] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 119
            [name:protected] => Holland
            [code:protected] => NL
            [stringIndex:protected] => NETHERLANDS
        )

    [Nya Zeeland] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 122
            [name:protected] => Nya Zeeland
            [code:protected] => NZ
            [stringIndex:protected] => NEW_ZEALAND
        )

    [Polen] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 138
            [name:protected] => Polen
            [code:protected] => PL
            [stringIndex:protected] => POLAND
        )

    [Spanien] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 161
            [name:protected] => Spanien
            [code:protected] => ES
            [stringIndex:protected] => SPAIN
        )

    [Sverige] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 166
            [name:protected] => Sverige
            [code:protected] => SE
            [stringIndex:protected] => SWEDEN
        )

    [Schweiz] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 167
            [name:protected] => Schweiz
            [code:protected] => CH
            [stringIndex:protected] => SWITZERLAND
        )

    [England] => Country Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 185
            [name:protected] => England
            [code:protected] => GB
            [stringIndex:protected] => UNITED_KINGDOM
        )

)
```

When I test it with the same indexes, but with the values of simple strings instead of my `Country` objects, it sorts correctly. When I test it with the same indexes, but with empty `Test` objects instead of my `Country` objects, again it sorts correctly. But in this particular case, it returns the wrong result. They aren't sorted by any values inside the object either, all the values seem random.

The `Country` class is extremely simple:

```
class Country {

   protected $id;
   protected $name;
   protected $code;
   protected $stringIndex;

}
```

What could by the cause?

Comment: Is it really `Osterrike`, or something like `Österrike`? I don't believe the array sort functions are at all unicode aware.

Comment: It's `Osterrike` because I removed `Ö` for testing purposes. That character was my first suspision.

Comment: Then try manually replacing the umlauted version with a plain ascii O and see if it sorts correctly. There's no way ksort would fail on ascii text, but I'll bet you a shiny penny it'll screw up on the accented/unicode versions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, or maybe you misunderstood me. I did already remove the umlauts. As I wrote, it's `Osterrike` because I removed `Ö` for testing purposes, and it still sorts incorrectly. As per the exact array in my post (which is the direct output from `printr()`)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. See this test script: http://pastebin.com/sTdxB0Lk

Comment: Oh, I managed to find the cause... I ended up with HTML tags in the array indexes, and I couldn't see them in the `print_r()`, but only when I examined the source code.. Sorry to have wasted your time, and I really appreciate you trying to help. At least you get to keep the shiny penny ^_^

Comment: Ah yeah. never trust what your browser displays when you're debugging web-based code. Since it's job is basically to LIE to you about what it received (e.g. rendering anything it thinks is html), you should ALWAYS do a 'view source' first.

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answering since this'll be really ugly as a comment:

I can't duplicate your `O` coming first:

code:

```
<?php

$foo = array(
   'P' => 'regular p',
   'Ö' => 'umlaut o',
   'O' => 'regular o',
   'A' => 'regular A'
);
```

var_dump($foo);
ksort($foo);
var_dump($foo);

Result:

```
array(4) {
  ["P"]=>
  string(9) "regular p"
  ["Ö"]=>
  string(8) "umlaut o"
  ["O"]=>
  string(9) "regular o"
  ["A"]=>
  string(9) "regular A"
}
array(4) {
  ["A"]=>
  string(9) "regular A"
  ["O"]=>
  string(9) "regular o"
  ["P"]=>
  string(9) "regular p"
  ["Ö"]=>
  string(8) "umlaut o"
}
```

As you can see, the `Ö` does sort incorrectly, but it sorts to the END of the array, not the beginning.

Comment: Managed to find the cause (comment in my original post). It was completely my mistake. Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score -1):

My answer's too late, I think, but it seems like array has been sorted by `stringIndex` field of Country Object.

Maybe (just **maybe**, I don't know exactly) because of SORT_STRING flag ksort tries to fing elements with defined `string` type, but if it couldn't, then, it tries to find keys with "string" keyword like `stringIndex` in Country object.